# What does the term "simple" in the phrase "simple whole number ratio" mean in Gay Lussac's law?

Tags: gas-laws

What does the term "simple" mean in the phrase "simple whole number ratio" in Gay Lussac's law?
I have searched this site as well as different sites on the internet. The answer to one question on this site states that it indicates that the numbers are small whole numbers. Another site stated that the terms of the ratio are not decimal numbers while another site states that the terms of the ratio are in simplest terms that is reduced form.

Comment: Related: [Law of Multiple Proportions: What is the significance of small whole numbers?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3975/7951)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3/2 is simple. 45498334/9232493 is not.

The reason it works is because reactions of gases producing gases involve relatively simple compounds. If they were complicated, the molecular weight would likely be high enough that the substance would not be a gas.

This is akin to Loong's comment about the Law of Multiple Proportions, which also mentions "small whole number ratios." The difference is that for the Law of Multiple Proportions, "small" ratios doesn't apply in the case of something like palytoxin ($\ce{C129H223N3O54}$).

But palytoxin isn't a gas. For the reason mentioned above, you're almost certain to get simple coefficients for gas to gas reactions.

Comment: So "small" here only means that it is not large and not anything else like decimal, in simplest terms. Correct?

Comment: Yes. It's just from the fact that the stoichiometric ratios for gas reactants producing gas products are small and simple.

Comment: One more question: Don't you mean that the volumes are simple after reducing them to the lowest terms? Otherwise they may be large(since we can take any volume of gases as reactants) but still, they have a common factor and on dividing them by this common factor they become small (simple), i.e., to say that, in the ratio of the volumes in their lowest terms, the volumes are simple.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with volumes. It's just ratios of atoms. You just happen to be using gases, so assuming their ideal (they're not) you could argue that the number of moles are related to the volumes, but that hides the information encoded in the stoichiometry of each substance.

Comment: What do you mean by saying " but that hides the information encoded in the stoichiometry of each substance"?

Comment: And by the way, since ratio of volumes and the ratio of amount of the substance are equivalent, isn't what i said still valid?

Comment: What you said is only valid if (1) you assume the gases are ideal and (2) if you assume that the reactants are gases. But the law of multiple proportions applies to the formulas for all simple compounds. You've just selected a very specific example to look at, but doing so hides the full extend of where the law can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

It means that both terms are reduced to the smallest whole number possible so that the numerator and denominator are co prime.